# Firing Single Photon

Tags: visible-light, photons, double-slit-experiment, wave-particle-duality

We know (or pretend to know) what will happen if we fire one photon at a time and let it pass through slit/slits. But what if we don't use slit/slits and fire photons one at a time at a screen? What are the results? Does it land at the same position or does something strange occur?

(Sorry, I couldn't find one on the internet what I was looking for.)
Also, inform me about the ongoing research on wave-particle duality.

Comment: Whatever device you use to create that photon state has an angle dependent radiation pattern and an effective aperture and the combination of the two will determine what's on the screen. For optical photons this will differ in nothing from what one expects for any other light source. Neither does the double slit, by the way. Quantum electrodynamics doesn't produce any obvious signature until we are either doing precision atomic physics or deal with 1MeV+ gammas.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get your point either! Well here I want you to just ignore the source. (well if is has strong effects on final projection then we can consider).

Comment: In theory you can ignore whatever you want, in practice there is no difference between a source, one slit, two or ten thousand. If the radiation characteristics matters (if you are designing an optical system like a microscope or projector, it usually does), then you have to measure what it is and you have to use that to achieve what you want. If it doesn't matter, then you are lucky.